# Transform list cell in data frame into rows

Tags: json, r

I'm sorry for no code to replicate, I can provide a picture only. See it below please.

A data frame with Facebook insights data prepared from JSON consists a column "values" with list values. For the next manipulation I need to have only one value in the column. So the row 3 on picture should be transformed into two (with list content or value directly):

```
post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique   lifetime   list(like = 38)
post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique   lifetime   list(share = 11)
```

If there are 3 or more values in data frame list cell, it should make 3 or more single value rows.

Do you know how to do it?

---

I use this code to get the json and data frame:

```
i <- fromJSON(post.request.url)
i <- as.data.frame(i$insights$data)
```

---

[image]

---

Edit:

- There will be no deeper nesting, just this one level.
- The list is not needed in the result, I need just the values and their names.

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(i)` as part of your question and also show what your desired output would be.

Comment: Actually, why do you want to keep the values column as lists in the first place?

Comment: Will the nesting ever be deeper than what you have here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you're starting with something that looks like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), period = "lifetime")
mydf$values <- list(list(value = 42), list(value = 5), 
                    list(value = list(like = 38, share = 11)),
                    list(value = list(like = 38, share = 13)))
```

---

```
 str(mydf)
## 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ a     : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3 4
##  $ period: Factor w/ 1 level "lifetime": 1 1 1 1
##  $ values:List of 4
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ value: num 42
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ value: num 5
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ value:List of 2
##   .. .. ..$ like : num 38
##   .. .. ..$ share: num 11
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ value:List of 2
##   .. .. ..$ like : num 38
##   .. .. ..$ share: num 13
## NULL
```

---

Instead of retaining lists in your output, I would suggest flattening out the data, perhaps using a function like this:

```
myFun <- function(indt, col) {
  if (!is.data.table(indt)) indt <- as.data.table(indt)
  other_names <- setdiff(names(indt), col)
  list_col <- indt[[col]]
  rep_out <- sapply(list_col, function(x) length(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)))
  flat <- {
    if (is.null(names(list_col))) names(list_col) <- seq_along(list_col)
    setDT(tstrsplit(names(unlist(list_col)), ".", fixed = TRUE))[
      , val := unlist(list_col, use.names = FALSE)][]
  }
  cbind(indt[rep(1:nrow(indt), rep_out)][, (col) := NULL], flat)
}
```

Here's what it does with the "mydf" I shared:

```
myFun(mydf, "values")
##    a   period V1    V2    V3 val
## 1: A lifetime  1 value    NA  42
## 2: B lifetime  2 value    NA   5
## 3: C lifetime  3 value  like  38
## 4: C lifetime  3 value share  11
## 5: D lifetime  4 value  like  38
## 6: D lifetime  4 value share  13
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't put into operation the part setDT in your code. There should be strsplit instead of tstrsplit I think, but it still says: 

Error in setDT(strsplit(names(unlist(list_col)), ".", fixed = TRUE)) : 
  All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length

I'm not very familiar with data table yet.

Comment: @Larssen, `tstrsplit` is a function in recent versions of "data.table" and is important to this answer.